# managed object method signature

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have managed objects given below; following warning raised for addCratesObject in the initFruitStand method. Why does it complain that it does not match the signature although it matches? What is the problem?

> In function
> '-[FruitStandViewController initFruitStand:]':
>
> 'FruitStand' may not respond to -addCratesObject:
>
> '(Messages without a matching method signature will be
> assumed to return 'id' and accept
> '...' as arguments.)

**MyViewController.m**

```
#import "FruitStand.h"
#import "Crate.h"

- (IBAction) initFruitStand: (id) sender {
    FruitStand * stand = (FruitStand *) [NSEntityDescription 
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FruitStand" 
        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    Crate * crateOne = (Crate *) [NSEntityDescription   
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Crate" 
        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [stand addCratesObject:crateOne];
}
```

**FruitStand.h**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Crate;
@interface FruitStand :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* standName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* crates;
@end

@interface FruitStand (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addCratesObject:(Crate *)value;
- (void)removeCratesObject:(Crate *)value;
- (void)addCrates:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeCrates:(NSSet *)value;
@end
```

**FruitStand.m**

```
#import "FruitStand.h"
#import "Crate.h"
@implementation FruitStand
@dynamic standName;
@dynamic crates;
@end
```

**Crates.h**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface Crate :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* fruits;
@end

@interface Crate (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addFruitsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeFruitsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addFruits:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeFruits:(NSSet *)value;
@end
```

**Crates.m**

```
#import "Crate.h"
@implementation Crate 
@dynamic fruits;
@end
```

Comment: Although I can't see a reason why you would need to, try importing your Crate.h header in your FruitStand.h interface instead of using the @class declaration.

Comment: data modeler creates them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway i have found the problem. there is another version of the same file in another folder which seems to be deleted but still exists and that causes the warning.

Comment: That's a part of the core data versioning feature. Manually delete the file first and then create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

As Les said; "That's pretty bizarre, Gus.".

Try cleaning the project and rebuilding.   Alternatively, use the "Preprocess" menu item to show what the compiler is trying to compile for MyViewController.m.   See what the compiler thinks the definition of FruitStand is within that compilation unit.